# Define correctly and automatized eastern time for "Last Refreshed On" visual in Power BI

Tags: datetime, powerbi, data-analysis, powerquery, m

I have a published dashboard that is refreshed every 30 minutes, in there I have a card where I put the "Last Refreshed On" datetime with Eastern Time format when the dashboard was refreshed by Power BI services, I want to avoid the manual change of the hours (behind UTC) based on the day light savings for each year.

Currently I defined this EST time calculation based on the next M script:

```
let
Source = #table(type table[Date Last Refreshed=datetime],{{DateTimeZone.UtcNow()}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date Last Refreshed", type datetime}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom Last Refresh", each [Date Last Refreshed]+ #duration(0,-4,0,0)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date Last Refreshed"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom Last Refresh", "Date Last Refreshed"}})

in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for daylight saving adjustments (I am in the East too):

```
let
ESTAdjustment = (InputDateTimeAsUTC as datetimezone, UTCAdjustmentAmount as number) =>
let
CurrentYear = Date.Year( DateTimeZone.SwitchZone( InputDateTimeAsUTC, UTCAdjustmentAmount ) ),
DaylightSavingsStart = Date.StartOfWeek( #datetimezone( CurrentYear, 3, 14, 0, 0, 0, UTCAdjustmentAmount, 0 ), Day.Sunday ) + #duration( 0, 2, 0, 0 ),
DaylightSavingsEnd = Date.StartOfWeek( #datetimezone( CurrentYear, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0, UTCAdjustmentAmount + 1, 0 ), Day.Sunday ) + #duration( 0, 2, 0, 0 ),
AdjustForDaylightSavingsTime = if InputDateTimeAsUTC >= DaylightSavingsStart and InputDateTimeAsUTC < DaylightSavingsEnd then UTCAdjustmentAmount + 1 else UTCAdjustmentAmount,
AdjustToEST = DateTimeZone.RemoveZone(InputDateTimeAsUTC) + #duration(0, AdjustForDaylightSavingsTime, 0, 0)
in
AdjustToEST
in
ESTAdjustment
```